# Strange response from the build at gitlab

Tags: python, selenium, gitlab

I have the strange behaviour at the code, if anyone could help me will be appreciated. The bug is when I run my test(the test is for python automation with using selenium and chromedriver) at the local it work perfectly But when I build it over the gitlab and run the pipeline the test will be failed, the reason is because the actual and the inputed value are not the same(but actually both are identical) the actual must be like this 329 328 xxxx but it change it to 923328xxxx.
I am using python selenium and chromedriver

Thanks

Comment: Check your environmental variables.

Comment: it would help if you included your ci file and an example job output for people to get a better idea of what you're talking about

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response. The problem was because at the gitlab chromedriver was version 74 and this strange behavior happened because of it, I have update the chtomedriver to 77 now it is working perfectly. cheers